# Handle rotation in Exoplayer for both portrait and landscape layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, video, exoplayer

I have an app in which user could play there video files available on their SD card. I have used exo-player 2 for playing videos.

My app has two different layouts for both landscape and portrait mode. I know exo-player 2 could handle rotation automatically but when I change the layout. it's not handling it.

In Portrait layout, there is a recycled view that contains list of other videos. I want this rotation behaviour get handled in a proper manner. I also tried for saving the current position in bundle in onSaveInstance but this also does not works for me. Please enlighten me to go for a better work around for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you forked the ExoPlayer 2 demo code, pay attention to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. At `PlayerActivity` section, it added `android:configChanges="orientation|..."`, which means when orientation changes, the activity will not be re-created, so the `layout-land` will not be deployed. Remove `"orientation"` config, it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

in manifest.xml

```
<activity
 android:name=".PlayVideoActivity"
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"
>
```

in activity
[enter link description here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/ima/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/imademo/MainActivity.java)

this [playerManager.java](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/ima/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/imademo/PlayerManager.java)
and this is for [layout](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/ima/src/main/res/layout/main_activity.xml)